# Redirecting file line by line in MS command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, redirect, command-prompt

I'm surprised I've never had to do this before, or probably if I have I "cheated" using vbs, Python or similar. Anyway, in the command shell, I want to load a file from disk, then for each line in that file, call a program with the arguments equal (or forming part of) the line form the file

So I want to call a program mycommand for each line in the file. I want to do a literal concatenation with the file output into the last argument (argument c)for mycommand:

mycommand -a arg1 -b arg2 -c < myFileWithArgParameterLineByLine.txt

Is there an easy way of doing this, or will I have to write a batch script?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the cmd line:

```js
for /f "usebackq delims=" %I in ("txtfile.txt") do mycommand -a arg1 -b arg2 -c %I
```

In a batch script, do the same thing, but with `%%I`.

```js
@echo off
setlocal

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("txtfile.txt") do mycommand -a arg1 -b arg2 -c %%I
```

Do `help for` in a cmd console for more info.  If you need explicitly to quote argument C to ensure it's treated as a single token or if the arguments might contain special characters (like a pipe or ampersand), then `-c "%~I"`.

From the cmd console:

```js
for /f "usebackq delims=" %I in ("txtfile.txt") do mycommand -a arg1 -b arg2 -c "%~I"
```